# Go fmt on a whole source tree

Tags: go

I have a project currently organized something like this:

```
~/code/go
         /bin
         /pkg
         /src
             /proj/main.go
                  /some_package/package.go
                  /some_other_package/some_other_package.go
```

Now if I want to use the `go fmt` tool on my whole project it seems that the only way is to do it separately for each directory in my projects source tree:

```
go fmt proj
go fmt proj/package
go fmt proj/some_other_package
```

Is there some way to tell the fmt command to run on the whole source tree?

Comment: Interesting. The `go fmt` documentation I have says it's recursive, but I can observe that it isn't.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use three dots (`...`) as a wildcard. So for example, the following command will format all github.com packages:

```
go fmt github.com/...
```

This wildcard also works with other go commands like `go list`, `go get` and so. There is no need to remember such an ugly find command.

Comment: @Chris, Using `...` as the wildcard is explained [there](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Description_of_package_lists)

Comment: I wonder why it is done this way as opposed to just using standard wildcard patterns like : `github.com/*` or globbing syntax like `github.com/**/*.go`

Answer (score 94):

If you use `gofmt` instead of `go fmt`, it's recursive. For example, following command

```
gofmt -s -w .
```

(notice the little dot at end) recursively formats, simplifies, and saves result into every file under current directory. I have a shell alias `gf` defined as `gofmt -s -w .` and find it quite handy.

Try `gofmt -l .` (*list files whose formatting differs from gofmt's*) first if you want :-)

Comment: `gofmt -l -s -w .` yields a behavior similar to `go fmt` (saving the files & printing the files that have been modified). Without the `-l` flag, the file names are not printed.

Comment: `git ls-files | grep ".go$" | xargs gofmt -l -s -w` to only do this to source files which are checked in to your repo.

Comment: does that affect only go files or all files in the directory?

Answer (score 55):

Also, you can try to run command:

```
go fmt ./...
```

from your project directory.

Comment: Doesn't work if `.` is a symbolic link. I found [Song's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333931/1102648) works with symlink.

Answer (score 6):

```
find proj -type f -iregex '.*\.go' -exec go fmt '{}' +
```

#### Explanation

- `find proj`: find everything in this directory...

  - `-type f`: ...that is a file
  - `-iregex '.*\.go'`: ...and case-insensitively matches the regular expression `.*\.go`
- ...and execute `go fmt` followed by as many matched files as the operating system can handle passing to an executable in one go.

Comment: Nice command, it's too bad the fmt tool can't do that automatically. I did make a couple of tweaks though: `find src` instead of `find proj` to run it from `$GOROOT`, and `\;` instead of `+` since the fmt tool doesn't work when it's given files that are in different directories.

Comment: Useful command, but I would like to  do something like this  `git status | egrep '\.go$'  .... ` and use your command  how can I do that?

Comment: @Cristian: You'll probably need to do some processing with `awk` or `cut` or something to munge it down to just a list of file names; once that's done, though, you should be able to use `xargs`, e.g. `... | xargs go fmt`.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using GoLand IDE, right click on project and you will find `Go Tools`.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The command `gofmt  ./...` mentioned by some, does not work on Windows (at least on my Win7).

Instead of it, I used `gofmt -d .\` which works recursively. I use the `-d` flag because I want to list the changes I need to make in order to pass the check.

NB: `golint  ./...` does work on Windows, just `gofmt  ./...` doesn't.