# Any tools rebase a branch in Git while running go fmt each commit separately?

Tags: git, go, indentation, git-rebase, gofmt

I wish to rebuild/rebase all commits in a Git branch `X` using a source code formatting tool like `go fmt` or `indent`.

I'd expect the workflow to roughly consist of making a new branch off `master` and iterating the following with `$_` ranging over the commits in `X`:

```
git cherry-pick $_
go fmt ...
git commit -a --amend
```

Or maybe even

```
git cherry-pick -n $_
go fmt ...
git cherry-pick --continue
```

I wouldn't expect `-n` and `--continue` to play together like that, though.  Also, one should naturally do a `go fmt` commit to `X` and `go diff X new` when done.

However, there are many steps that can go wrong with this procedure, like the `-a` seeking to change files that weren't changed in the original commit, `go fmt` confusing Git's patching, Git changing the commit dates, etc.

None of that is particularly troublesome, but if a quick tool or simpler workflow does this more cleanly, then I'd love to know about it.

Comment: Way to tedious. Check out `git filter-branch` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if a quick tool or simpler workflow does this more cleanly, then I'd love to know about it.

As [Joseph K. Strauss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354956/joseph-k-strauss) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738571/any-tools-rebase-a-branch-in-git-while-running-go-fmt-each-commit-separately/27744800#comment43899727_27738571), [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) should be enough, plus [`go fmt` using the three dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321739/6309):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'go fmt ...'
```

You can read (much) more on filter-branch at "[`git filter-branch` - discard the changes to a set of files in a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274266/6309)".

That command will run against all local branch, and will change the history (since new SHA1 will be generated for each modified commit).
A `git push --force` might be needed to publish the new history to its upstream repo: do warn the other collaborators, for them to reset their local repos.